# Не запускается видео

Tags: windows, видео

Есть видео полученное с видео регистратора. Оно было разибито на части и заархивировано. Благополучно разархивировал, получил один видео файл. При попытке его запустить выбивает ошибку:

> Не удается найти комбинацию фильтров для просмотра потока. Error Num:80040218

Видеоплеер  KM Player
Дополнительная информация которую мне показывает плеер. Есть ли какой-то способ все же посмотреть видео?

```
--------------------
    BINARY INFO
--------------------
FileName : AMBA0236.MOV
Data :
 00 00 00 18 66 74 79 70 71 74 20 20 00 00 00 00         ftypqt      
 71 74 20 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 7F E4 66 72 65 65      qt         free

--------------------
[Информация о файле]
--------------------
C:\Users\Drop\AppData\Roaming\Skype\My Skype Received     Files\AMBA0236\AMBA0236.MOV
  General
    Complete name : C:\Users\Drop\AppData\Roaming\Skype\My Skype Received     Files\AMBA0236\AMBA0236.MOV
Format : MPEG-4
    Format profile : QuickTime
Codec ID : qt   0000.00 (qt  )
File size : 39.8 MiB



--------------------
PLAYBACK INFO
--------------------

[Видеоданные]
Декодер -No codec

[Аудиоданные]
Декодер -No codec

[Обычный видео DSP]
Internal brightness: 100%

[Расширенный видео DSP]
+Video Plugin

[Аудио DSP]
+Pre amplification: Main: (100%)
+Auto Volume Control
+3D Effect: 5000
+Audio Plugin


[KMPlayer]
+Version: 4.1.5.8(16 472 808, 05.01.2017 5:42:44)
+libcodec.dll: (4 548 096, 29.01.2016 11:04:34)
+libmplay.dll: (538 112, 29.01.2016 11:04:42)
+PProcDLL.dll: 1.0.0.1(1 769 472, 29.01.2016 11:04:48)
+LibDTS.dll: (178 174, 29.01.2016 11:04:48)
+liba52.dll: (73 063, 29.01.2016 11:04:46)
+libfaad2.dll: (335 155, 29.01.2016 11:04:46)
+libmad.dll: (123 036, 29.01.2016 11:04:44)
+libmpeg2.dll: (154 644, 29.01.2016 11:04:48)
+theora.dll: (200 864, 29.01.2016 11:04:30)
+OggVorbis.dll: (1 165 312, 29.01.2016 11:04:46)
+xviddll.dll: (758 319, 29.01.2016 11:04:48)
+Old_QUARTZ.DLL: 6.01.05.0319(770 048, 29.01.2016 11:04:48)
+AboutDll.dll: (105 472, 29.01.2016 11:04:46)
+DTView.dll: (98 304, 29.01.2016 11:04:50)
+ImLoader.dll: (856 064, 29.01.2016 11:04:48)
+MediaInfo.dll: 0.7.89.0(4 474 216, 02.11.2016 3:56:50)
```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не относится к программированию

Comment: дак кодеков не хватает небось. поставьте какой-нить klite codec pack

Comment: @teran klite codec pack стоит

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov восстановление битых файлов относится к тематике данного сайта, на сколько я могу судить

Comment: а вы загрузите куда нить во вконтакт или ютуб  и узнаете, битый файл или нет :)

Comment: @teran  ютуб говорит: 
> Что-то пошло не так. Это точно был файл поддерживаемого формата?
значит все же  с ним что-то не так

Comment: надо полагать, что исходного файла уже нет и контрольную сумму, например, не сравнить?

Comment: @teran файл был разбит на части. Они по отдельности есть. А Исходного файла нет

Comment: собирали архив той же версией архиватора? В общем, дальше хз что вам предложить, тут уже советы профильных специалистов нужны.

Comment: @teran, архивы собирал видеорегистратор и в таком виде предоставил видео он. В любом случае, спасибо за ваше вниманиие)

Comment: А можно ссылку на исходник? Или секретно?

Answer (score 1):

Не надо было сливать разбитые файлы. Просто вводите в адресную строку <свой формат> to avi и с помощью онлайн-конвертера переводите ваши фрагменты в формат avi. А потом уже соединяете ваши авишки.